# "Couldn't load plugin mmqgis due to an error when calling its classFactory() method"

Tags: python, mmqgis

Couldn't load plugin mmqgis due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

> ImportError: No module named mmqgis_kml_export_form  Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line
>   306, in startPlugin
>       plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)   File "C:/Users/Latha/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis__init__.py", line 17, in
>   classFactory
>       from mmqgis_menu import mmqgis_menu   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line
>   572, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:/Users/Latha/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_menu.py",
>   line 19, in 
>       from mmqgis_dialogs import *   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line
>   572, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:/Users/Latha/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_dialogs.py",
>   line 1800, in 
>       from mmqgis_kml_export_form import *   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line
>   572, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level) ImportError: No module named mmqgis_kml_export_form

Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.14.7-Essen Essen, ed8807c

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/Latha/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/Latha/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg
c:\osgeo4~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/Latha/.qgis2//python
C:\Users\Latha.qgis2\python\plugins\gearthview\ext-libs
C:\Users\Latha.qgis2\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms

I dont know how to work with programming languages, so I am not sure of what the error is and how to correct it.

I happen to clear a lot of my temporary files yesterday and i am not sure if that is the reason as to why this error has cropped up. I am unable to open any project or vector or raster layers.

I tried uninstalling QGIS and reinstalling it. But, I get the same error message.

Comment: It looks like the plugin is unable to find a python module that it requires to run (mmqgis_kml_export_form). Have you tried uninstalling/unloading and reinstalling/reloading the plugin?